# Opencart, Nivo slider controlNav active text color

Tags: opencart, nivo-slider

I'm trying to change the font color of just the active tabs on Nivo slider.

[image]

I have tried this but, it's not working;

```
.nivo-controlNav a:hover, .nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background:url(../image/a_active.png) repeat-y 0px 50%;
    --> color:#000 !important;
}
```

I have also, tried;

```
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
     color:#000 !important;
}
```

the file I'm editing is the slideshow.css

Comment: Could You provide us with a link to Your site? Also tell us in which file You have tried the above modifications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go check these styles:

```css
.nivo-controlNav a h1 {
    color: #E4007B;
    font: bold 15px/20px Arial;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

and add these after:

```css
.nivo-controlNav a.active h1 {
    color: #000;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: If you have a second, I have a problem trying to change the color of the text while hovering. I have the following but, the text in all boxes changes to white not just the one which is being hovered over.  .nivo-controlNav:hover h1 {
    color: #fff;
}